# Why does the contract owner receive less ETH than has been sent through payable transfer?

Tags: solidity, ethers.js

I'm developing an ERC-721 smart contract function that accepts donations in eth and mints an item in return. My function looks like the following:

```
contract RandNFT is ERC721URIStorage, Ownable {
  using Counters for Counters.Counter;
  Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;

  // We need to pass the name of our NFTs token and its symbol.
  constructor() ERC721 ("RandNFT", "RAND") {}

  function mint(string memory tokenURI) payable external returns (uint256) {
    require(msg.value > 0 wei, 'Mint requires a donation of at least 1 wei.');
    
    _tokenIds.increment();
    uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();
    _safeMint(msg.sender, newItemId);
    _setTokenURI(newItemId, tokenURI);
    payable(owner()).transfer(msg.value);
    
    return newItemId;
  }
}
```

When I test this function, however, it seems that eth has been lost during the transfer.

```js
const DONATION_IN_ETH = '0.00001'
const donation = ethers.utils.parseEther(DONATION_IN_ETH)

it('successfully pays to the owner', async function () {
  const contractFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory('ElleNFT')
  const contract = await contractFactory.deploy()
  await contract.deployed()
  const [owner, sender] = await ethers.getSigners()
  const oldBalance = Number(bigNumberToString(await owner.getBalance()))
  await contract.connect(sender).mint('FAKE_TOKEN_URI', { value: donation })
  const newBalance = Number(bigNumberToString(await owner.getBalance()))
  const donationAmt = Number(bigNumberToString(donation))
  expect(newBalance - oldBalance).toBe(donationAmt)
})
```

My test fails, showing the following results:

```sh
expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

Expected: 10000000000000
Received: 9999998779392
```

I'm not sure why this is the case. Why is there such a big difference (1,220,608 wei) between the expected and received amount?

FWIW, here's my bigNumberToString helper function:

```
import { ethers } from 'hardhat'
import type { BigNumber } from 'ethers'

export function bigNumberToString(bn: BigNumber): string {
  return ethers.BigNumber.from(bn).toString()
}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a truncation error. When you convert the type from BigNumber to Number you're losing some of the data.

Instead, keep oldBalance and newBalance as BigNumber and get the difference using newBalance.sub(oldBalance)

```
it("successfully pays to the owner", async function () {
    const contractFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("RandNFT");
    const contract = await contractFactory.deploy();
    await contract.deployed();
    const [owner, sender] = await ethers.getSigners();
    const oldBalance = await owner.getBalance();
    await contract.connect(sender).mint("FAKE_TOKEN_URI", { value: donation });
    const newBalance = await owner.getBalance();
    const balanceDiff = newBalance.sub(oldBalance);
    expect(balanceDiff).to.equal(donation);
});
```